# Can someone tell me what coding language this is?

Tags: elf, file-type

I have this script file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16328940/storagefolderforapk%27s/btool) that contains a lot of odd characters such as these

```
EOT NUL SOH DLE CAN FF SYN BS US FS à 8 F ÿ ÷ 6 ï
```

Can anyone tell me what language this is? From about 2 hours Googling around I've broken down and asked here. I found that it matches ASCII characters somewhat but when I put it into ASCII decoders it comes back as ??? plus the characters are in black boxes that won't copy to my clipboard.  I don't really care so much about decoding it as getting regular text to that language.  Ff it is encrypted can anyone tell me method used?  It's a shell script from what I can tell because i can run it using terminal emulator on my Android phone.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Without even looking at it it seems like you're looking at a compiled file of some sort (or some random binary format that's not executable).  Where did you find this?  Any reason you suspect it's a program?

Comment: @templatetypedef: That's what I thought, but the `NUL` is a bit suspicious to me (as is the `SYN`, which is an ASCII character, etc.)... idk.

Comment: @Mehrdad- I think that those are just the longer names for the low-order ASCII characters (control codes).  This really looks it's just a binary executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'file' says:

> btool: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

And objdump -R says:

```
btool:     file format elf32-little

DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE
00009154 UNKNOWN           __sF
00009124 UNKNOWN           _ZN7android7String8D1Ev
00009128 UNKNOWN           printf
0000912c UNKNOWN           _ZN7android16BackupDataReaderC1Ei
00009130 UNKNOWN           puts
00009134 UNKNOWN           __libc_init
00009138 UNKNOWN           fprintf
0000913c UNKNOWN           _ZN7android16BackupDataReader16ReadEntityHeaderEPNS_7String8EPj
00009140 UNKNOWN           strcmp
00009144 UNKNOWN           _ZN7android7String8C1Ev
00009148 UNKNOWN           _ZN7android16BackupDataReader14ReadNextHeaderEPbPi
0000914c UNKNOWN           _ZN7android16BackupDataReaderD1Ev
00009150 UNKNOWN           open
```

'file's manpage says about it's history:

> There has been a file command in every UNIX since at least Research Version 4 (man page dated November, 1973).  The System V version introduced one significant major change: the external list of magic types.  This slowed the program down slightly but made it a lot more flexible.
>
> This program, based on the System V version, was written by Ian Darwin  without looking at anybody else's source code.
>
> John Gilmore revised the code extensively, making it better than the first version.  Geoff Collyer found several inade-quacies and provided some magic file entries.  Contributions by the `&' operator by Rob McMahon, cudcv@warwick.ac.uk, 1989.
>
> Guy Harris, guy@netapp.com, made many changes from 1993 to the present.
>
> Primary development and maintenance from 1990 to the present by Christos Zoulas (christos@astron.com).
>
> Altered by Chris Lowth, chris@lowth.com, 2000: Handle the -i option to output mime type strings, using an alternative magic file and internal logic.
>
> Altered by Eric Fischer (enf@pobox.com), July, 2000, to identify character codes and attempt to identify the languages of non-ASCII files.
>
> Altered by Reuben Thomas (rrt@sc3d.org), 2007 to 2008, to improve MIME support and merge MIME and non-MIME magic, supportdirectories as well as files of magic, apply many bug fixes and improve the build system.
>
> The list of contributors to the `magic' directory (magic files) is too long to include here.  You know who you are; thank you.  Many contributors are listed in the source files.

Comment: Huh... what's 'file'? Is that a Linux tool or something? Seems interesting...

Comment: 'man file' says: file -- determine file type

Comment: Now seriously, it's a standard tool on unix/linux systems. I've added a quote about 'file's history to the answer.

Comment: @sinelaw: Interesting... I don't really use *nix (I've just installed Ubuntu recently, and I rarely use it) so I didn't know about it.

Comment: Okay so i just did the file command myself thanks for the info i got the same out put that its a ELF 32-bit LSB executable file but how do i create one of these myself?

Comment: user577732, you have to know what an ELF file is, first. Basically it's a compiled executable file (source could be C, C++ or anything else that is compiled). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: Well it should be a shell script i think that was compiled since i can run it from terminal on my android phone i'm just looking to compile one of my scripts as well

Answer (score 0):

If you open the script with notepad, it contains raw strings like "ELF", "ibstdc++", so I guess its C++.